# Accessing objects via closure from named function expression is slow in latest safari

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, safari

In latest safari (5.1.7) and mobile safari, there is a huge performance difference between named and anonymous functions when accessing objects via closure. Please see http://jsperf.com/nfe-fe/2

This was not an issue in earlier versions of safari but it seems to be a problem in later versions.

Is there any way to improve the performance of the named function expression? I like named functions for two reasons - easy to review stack trace and have better logs using .name property. The bug in latest safari is slowing our application's performance terribly.

I have given below the test code used in jsperf:

Preparation code

```
  Benchmark.prototype.setup = function() {

    var FunctionExpressionCreator = function () {

      var i = 0;
      this.a = function () {
        return ++i;
      }

      this.test = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
          this.a();
        }
      }
    };

    var functionExprObject = new FunctionExpressionCreator();

    var NamedFunctionExpressionCreator = function () {
      var i = 0;
      this.a = function a() {
        return ++i;
      }

      this.test = function test() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
          this.a();
        }
      }
    };

    var namedFunctionExprObject = new NamedFunctionExpressionCreator();
  };
```

Test1: namedFunctionExprObject.test();

Test2: functionExprObject.test();

Test1 runs 85% slower than Test2 on recent iOS and Safari 5.1.7, but both are comparable in earlier versions.